# Cargar sólo ciertos ficheros de lenguage en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Quería saber si existe alguna forma en Laravel (7) de cargar sólo los ficheros de lenguaje de determinadas zonas/secciones. Con esto me refiero a que, por ejemplo, si un usuario entra en "Users", cargar sólo los ficheros de "users" y "general".

Por lo que se, Laravel parece cargar siempre todos los ficheros, lo cual considero innecesario. Sobre todo cuando el número de índices en los arrays de etiquetas empiezan a hacerse grandes, creo que se hace necesaria una solución al respecto.

Se que en otros Frameworks como por ejemplo CodeIngiter sí que se dispone de dicha opción, pero en Laravel he buscado varias veces algo parecido y no encuentro nada que solucione este problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con ficheros?

Comment: @JonathanOrta me refiero a los ficheros que figuran en cada una de las carpetas de lang/en o lang/es. Por ejemplo: lang/es/general.php, lang/es/users.php,...